Text generation using Ollama
I have installed the ollama server on my local system. I split created embeddings out of a document and fed those to the model. The model is able to retrieve the correct chunk of text when asked a question. However, it does not generate its own answer. How do I make the model generate its own answers?
Model used for embedding: all-minilm
Model used for question-answering: Llama3

Do you happen to have the code? It's hard to help you debug without code
